# Binding with a DataTemplate for System DataType

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm

This may either be a silly question or i've searched for the wrong words:
I have a ComboBox and want to display doubles using a custom converter (showing the equivalent fraction).
In the DataTemplate i have to specify a DataType, which is Double, but i don't know how to specity it. I'm sure there is a simple way to do so!

Adding the System-namespace to the window doesn't compile

```
<Window ... xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System" ...>
```

Simply typing Double or System.Double in DataType doesn't either.

And defining a ViewModel for a simple Double-Type can't be the solution either, can it?!

This is my code so far:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Gains}" SelectedItem="{Binding Gain, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType=" ??????? fract">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ., Converter=fractConverter}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

**FULL SOLUTION:**

Using the System namespace as *sys:* works!
*Gains* is a List<Double>
*Gain* is a Double

```
<Window ... xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" ...>
```

The Combobox works like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Gains}" SelectedItem="{Binding Gain, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Double}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource realConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Double}">
```

Comment: 'sys' alias has to be added as a spearate xmlns as it doesn't get added by default.

Comment: hm, when i add `;assembly=mscorlib` to the namespace definition it at least compiles... but the datatemplate still doesn't work even if it contains a Textblock saying 'lala'. It still uses ToString method to display the number.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify data templates - it's only used for picking up data type specific (implicit) ones:) Just omit your DataType.

Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx

as it looks quite close to what you're doing.

Comment: that was my first attempt, but i think it's not powerful enough. i want to display numbers <1 as fraction, e.g. 1/200 for 0.005

Comment: then convertes os the way to go.